# A question from Sieradski’s introduction to topology.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces

The following is a question from the book.
[image]

I’ve understood and solved part a) using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. However I don’t understand part b). I know it has something to do with the Banach’s fixed point theorem, since it’s a contraction in an Euclidean space. I request you to shed some light on this part.

Answer (score 0):

$Mx+m=0 \iff cMx + cm= 0 \iff x-cMx-cm = x \iff Ax -cm = x$.

Hence $x$ is a solution if and only if it is a fixed point of $x\mapsto Ax-cm$, which is a contraction because ...